# Web API & entitiy framework how to work with posted json array

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I try to write a post method for my asp.net web API.

The method shoulde be 
1. receive Json formated datastring with have single objects and one sub array.
2. write it in my database in two tables with have a 1:n relation.

It would be wonderfull if anyone can help me. 
I've no more idea how i can realise it

**Example of the Json data:**

```
[   
  {
    "User":"testuser",
    "CPGRP":21321321,   
    "Sex":"men",    
    "Name": "test", 
    "PointList":[
                      {
                  "Cost_I_Rea":"22202771.01",
                "Cost_TV":"213213210.0" ,
                "GRP":10,   
                "ID":0, 
                "ReichweiteID_F":1, 
            "RW_TV":"9.603",    
                "RW_Zuwgs":"9.603",
                      },
                      {
                        "Cost_I_Rea":"22202771.01",
                "Cost_TV":"213213210.0" ,
                "GRP":10,   
                "ID":0, 
                "ReichweiteID_F":1, 
            "RW_TV":"9.61103",  
                "RW_Zuwgs":"9.6043",
                      }
                   ]
    "Potenzial":213213,
    "ReichweiteID":0,   
    "ZielGRP":21321321
   }
]
```

**This is my Post Method now, but it's generate a 500 Error:**

```
// POST api/TVKurve

        [ResponseType(typeof(Points))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostPoints(Points points)
        {
            //if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            //{
            //    return BadRequest(ModelState);
            //}

            db.Points.Add(points);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            db.Entry(points).Reference(x => x.Reichweite).Load();
            var dto = new ReichweitePointsDto()
            {
                ReichweiteID = points.ReichweiteId,
                Sex = points.Reichweite.Geschlecht,
                Name = points.Reichweite.Name,
                CPGRP = points.Reichweite.CpGRP,
                Potenzial = points.Reichweite.Potenzial,
                ZielGRP = points.Reichweite.ZielGRP,
                User = points.Reichweite.Benutzer,
                PointList = new List<PointListDto>(),

            };

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = points.Id }, points);
        }
```

**and my data annotation Model:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace xms_ef_vers1.Models
{
    public class PointListDto
    {

        public PointListDto() { }

        public PointListDto(Points item)
        {
            ID = item.Id;
            GRP = item.GRP;
            RW_TV = item.RW_TV;
            Cost_TV = item.Cost_TV;
            RW_Zuwgs = item.Rw_ZuWGS;
            Cost_I_Rea = item.Cost_I_Rea;
            ReichweiteID_F = item.ReichweiteId;
        }

        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set;}

        [Required]
        public int GRP { get; set; }


        public decimal RW_TV { get; set; }
        public double Cost_TV { get; set; }
        public decimal RW_Zuwgs { get; set; }
        public decimal Cost_I_Rea { get; set; }
        public int ReichweiteID_F { get; set; }

        public Points ToEntity()
        {
            return new Points
            {
                Id = ID,
                GRP = GRP,
                RW_TV = RW_TV,
                Cost_TV = Cost_TV,
                Rw_ZuWGS = RW_Zuwgs,
                Cost_I_Rea = Cost_I_Rea,
                ReichweiteId = ReichweiteID_F,

            };
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You are confusing things, you said that you want to pass a single object with sub-array of points but your method accepts a Points type parameter which I can't see its declaration ? also, your json shows that you send an array of that object. can you double check please ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.

I ve got it.

Look here:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage PostReicheite(ReichweitePointsDto reichw)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                var reichwe = new Reichweite()
                {

                    Geschlecht = reichw.Geschlecht,
                    Name = reichw.Name,
                    CpGRP = reichw.CPGRP,
                    Potenzial = reichw.Potenzial,
                    ZielGRP = reichw.ZielGRP,
                    Benutzer = reichw.Benutzer,
                    PointListe = (from item in reichw.PointListe
                                  select new Points()
                                      {
                                          GRP = item.GRP,
                                          RW_TV = item.RW_TV,
                                          Cost_TV = item.Cost_TV,
                                          Rw_ZuWGS = item.RW_Zuwgs,
                                          Cost_I_Rea = item.Cost_I_Rea,
                                      }).ToList()
                };

                db.Reichweites.Add(reichwe);
                db.SaveChanges();

                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, reichwe);
                response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultAPI", new { id = reichwe.Id }));
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
         }
```

Now the Post Method do exactly what i need.
Only one bug, i've got an 500 status back can you say me why?

Best

Comment: Wrap your code in a try / catch and see what the actual exception is.